# Config ElasticBeanstalk with RDS using API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How do I create an EB environment with a RDS layer using the API (and not the GUI or CLI)?

I can configure an EB environment with a RDS layer using the GUI. But currently, I am using the API to create EB environments (via boto3 which appears to just be a wrapper around the REST API). I pass the same OptionSettings as the ones that are created by the GUI (namespace `aws:rds:dbinstance`), but this does not result in the creation of an RDS instance or layer. The only difference between my config and the one created by the GUI is a section that is created by the GUI that looks like:

```
Extensions:
  RDS.EBConsoleSnippet:
    Order: null
    SourceLocation: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-env-resources-us-west-2/eb_snippets/rds/rds.json
```

I have added this verbatim to a yaml file in the .ebextensions directory (this directory is then added to my deployment package), but still no dice.

Here are the relevant OptionSettings (resulting in options identical to the ones created by the GUI):

```
                {
                    'Namespace':'aws:ec2:vpc',
                    'OptionName': 'DBSubnets',
                    'Value': '<redacted>'
                },
                {
                    'Namespace':'aws:rds:dbinstance',
                    'OptionName': 'DBEngine',
                    'Value': 'mysql'
                },
                {
                    'Namespace':'aws:rds:dbinstance',
                    'OptionName': 'DBEngineVersion',
                    'Value': '5.6.23'
                },
                {
                    'Namespace':'aws:rds:dbinstance',
                    'OptionName': 'DBInstanceClass',
                    'Value': 'db.t2.micro'
                },
                {
                    'Namespace':'aws:rds:dbinstance',
                    'OptionName': 'DBUser',
                    'Value': os.environ['RDS_USER']
                },
                {
                    'Namespace':'aws:rds:dbinstance',
                    'OptionName': 'DBPassword',
                    'Value': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD']
                },
                {
                    'Namespace':'aws:rds:dbinstance',
                    'OptionName': 'DBAllocatedStorage',
                    'Value': '5'
                },
                {
                    'Namespace':'aws:rds:dbinstance',
                    'OptionName': 'MultiAZDatabase',
                    'Value': 'false'
                },
                {
                    'Namespace':'aws:rds:dbinstance',
                    'OptionName': 'DBDeletionPolicy',
                    'Value': 'snapshot'
                }
```

Comment: Were you able to deploy an RDS instance from the API?  I'm having the same issue, struggling to deploy an RDS instance with my elastic beanstalk instance.  About the only solution I could find was specifying a saved template.  But I really don't want to have to do that.

Comment: No the closest I got was something like Gustaf's answer but you don't the the EBS integrations you get if you go through the GUI

Answer (score 0):

You can define database when you create the environment like this:

```
eb create --database --database.engine mysql --region eu-west-1
```

Update:
You can also create an database using the resources tag in a config in .ebextensions something like this:

```
Resources:
    AWSEBRDSDatabase:
        Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
        Properties:
            AllocatedStorage: 5
            DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
            DBName: database_name
            Engine: mysql
            EngineVersion: 5.5
            MasterUsername: root
            MasterUserPassword: password
```

More information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html).

Comment: thank you but the questions specifies that I want to use the API and not the CLI